# Error: The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members:

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a flutter app. It was working perfectly on my intel Mac mini.

Now, I am trying to run my app on my new M1 Macbook Pro 2020.

I completed all the steps correctly and run successfully example counter Flutter app on my new M1 Macbook Pro 2020.

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=vscode

I downloaded the latest Flutter version & latest VSCode & Latest Xcode.

on This new M1 macbook:

**Flutter:** 3.3.4

**Xcode:** 14.0.1

**VSCode:** 1.17.2

In fact my project was working without any problem on my older intel Mac Mini but versions was older.

on my older Intel Mac Mini:

**Flutter:** I don't remember but I am sure that it was not 3.3.4

**Xcode:** I don't remember but I am sure that it was not 14.0.1

**VSCode:** I don't remember.

Now, I am trying to Start Debugging on iPhone 14 Pro Max(iOS 16) but it gives error.

```
  ../../../../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:407:7: Error: The
    non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members:
     - TextInputClient.insertTextPlaceholder
     - TextInputClient.removeTextPlaceholder
     - TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection
     - TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection
     - TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText
     - TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll
    Try to either
     - provide an implementation,
     - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
     - mark the class as abstract, or
     - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
```

There is no

> flutter_math_fork

dependency in my project but interestingly it says this library is problematic. How can it be possible? I did not use this library.

pubspec.yaml

```
name: app
description: Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1 

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  badges: ^2.0.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  dots_indicator: ^2.0.0
  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.3
  firebase_storage: ^9.0.0
  flutter_web_browser: ^0.14.0
  flutter_html: ^2.1.0
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.6.1
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  html: ^0.15.0
  html_unescape: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.1+3
  intl: ^0.17.0
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  line_icons: ^2.0.1
  lottie: ^1.1.0
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  provider: ^5.0.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  skeleton_text: ^3.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0
  youtube_plyr_iframe: ^2.0.7
  rounded_loading_button: ^2.0.5
  firebase_analytics: ^8.1.2
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.5.0
  the_apple_sign_in: ^1.1.1
  video_player: ^2.1.10
  flick_video_player: ^0.3.1
  flutter_icons:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/adarsh-technocrat/flutter-icons
  md2_tab_indicator:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/westdabestdb/md2_tab_indicator
      
  google_mobile_ads: ^1.0.1 #^0.13.2
  facebook_audience_network: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.0


  


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.0"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true #added later.
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"



# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/animation_files/
    - assets/translations/

  fonts:

    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 800

    - family: Open Sans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 500

    - family: Manrope
      fonts:
        # - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-Light.ttf
        #   weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-Medium.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Manrope-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 900
```

**Note that:** I changed only platform :ios, '14.0' in Podfile. It was platform :ios, '10.0'

10.0 --> 14.0

If I make it 10.0 in this new M1 Macbook Pro, it gives

> Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with
> '@available',

error.

I changed it 10.0 --> 14.0 to solve this problem but now it gives

```
 non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members:
```

error as I stated above.

I'm new to Flutter, how can I solve my problem?

**EDIT:**
@Jora's solution is not working because I think

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_math_fork: ^0.6.0
```

library conflicts with

```
provider: ^5.0.0

flick_video_player: ^0.3.1

flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.6.1

flutter_html: ^2.1.0
```

libraries. Then what is the simplest solution? Thanks...

Comment: I'd assume that one of the libaries you use, has a dependency itself on the problematic package flutter_math_fork. This is called transitive dependency. You can take a look at pubspec.lock to see if it is contained in there.
My guess would be that flutter_math_fork has some issue

Comment: I found [this related github issue](https://github.com/simpleclub-extended/flutter_math_fork/issues/7)

Comment: There is no flutter_math_fork in pubspec.lock.

Answer (score 1):

The [linked github issue](https://github.com/simpleclub-extended/flutter_math_fork/issues/7) mentions that this is a problem of `flutter_math_fork`.

You should upgrade it to a fixed version via

```
dependencies:
  flutter_math_fork: ^0.6.0
```

or

```
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_math_fork: ^0.6.0
```

Comment: Hi, I have no this library.

Comment: Hi again, I added dependency overrides but it gave https://ibb.co/m8JLWG2 error.